# Is it possible to create an app that automatically retunes slightly out-of-tune music to be A440 with Javascript?

Tags: html5-audio

One pet peeve I have with a lot of older rock music records from the 60's and 70's
is they sometimes are slightly of of tune with the standard a440 reference pitch, so playing along on my guitar sounds bad. Right now I manually adjust the pitch of the track by ear in Audacity, but this often takes some time. I was hoping there was something out there that could detect the frequency of the first few notes of a music file, analyze that and see how far it is from any standard A440 note, and then you could use that number to determine how much you needed to make the track sharp or flat to match A440 tuning.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to create an app that automatically retunes slightly out-of-tune music to be A440 with Javascript?

**Yes.**  Check out this [pitch detection demo by Chris Wilson](https://github.com/cwilso/PitchDetect).

There are some big caveats though, and they don't really have anything to do with JavaScript.

#### Voice Selection

What instruments do you care about?  Obviously wideband stuff like percussion is atonal... but it's still going to turn up in your audio, and will have a pitch.  How about the difference between a voice and wind instruments?  A lot of vocalists will go off pitch intentionally.  You will need to use bandpass fliters to get the range you care about, at a minimum.

#### Original Intonation

What about the instruments being in tune in the first place?  "Another one bites the dust" comes to mind as a rock record from the 70s that starts off terribly out of tune... and maybe intentionally.

#### Pyscoacoustics and Harmonics

Sometimes we hear things that aren't really there.  If I play a trombone down a scale, to the very bottom of its range, it will actually stop producing a fundamental... yet because I was playing a familiar scale downward, us humans will still perceive one.  This might not throw off your detection by a lot, but it will somewhat, particularly on those atonal-but-not-really percussion instruments.

In summary, this is possible but it's going to be a lot of work.  Please come back and post a link once you've done this!